# Links in REST response

Tags: rest, hateoas

In the HATEOAS paradigm, what do links in a REST response signify, an action or a resource? I have an order-form that has a type dropdown. Some advanced options fields are to be loaded in the form based on those selections.

Going by the HATEOAS paradigm, the client should not be expected to know or guess where to load those extra fields from. Hence, I included the 1 link for every option provided. The `rel` attribute on the link object is supposed to provide some kind of documentation about the intention of the link. Is this a correct implementation ?

The popular coffee shop example available on 'net (in Ian Robinson's talk and an article at InfoQ) uses links to identify next available state transitions. Are these equivalent in spirit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that your example is correct or incorrect but rather that it is a *compliant* hypermedia link. There are different types of hypermedia links and you just need to find the most appropriate. For example, it sometimes makes sense to separate the link relation to a resource from the linked resource. Using XML, you could do this:

```
<link rel="type1SpecialOptions" href="http:/yourDomain/specialOptions/type1" />
<link rel="type2SpecialOptions" href="http:/yourDomain/specialOptions/type2" />
```

instead of the still valid hypermedia link style:

```
<link specialOptions="http:/yourDomain/specialOptions/type1" />
<link specialOptions="http:/yourDomain/specialOptions/type2" />
```

Pick a type of link type that makes sense for your application. This [article on hypermedia links](http://amundsen.com/hypermedia/hfactor/) has a very brief explanation of the types of hypermedia links. It pretty much assumes you are familiar with the terminology of hypermedia and REST so look at the examples **first** and then follow the links for the different link types to get a better understanding of what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are several choices open to you:

1. Define custom rel values that signify that an action can be taken on the linked resource. Document these in your API docs. (preferably use self-documenting, dereferencable HTTP URIs as your rel values!)
2. Define in your media type documentation that certain hyperlinks in the document heirarchy represent resources that can have non-GET requests performed on them, and links elsewhere represent resources that only support GET. YOu can be as specific as you like here.
3. Use forms. Certain media types (XML, HTML) have a notion of forms. Hyperlinks that are the action of a form are explicitly actions. Be aware that without AJAX, browsers only support POST at present.
4. Use `OPTIONS` to return an `Allow:` header, providing information on actions that can be performed. This choice requires a second round-trip, but can be supported in addition to one or more of the above three.